# US Treasury Bill will Mature on Thurs, Oct 22 - how to re-invest part of if before Maturity

Tags: united-states, treasury

I purchased 13-week Bill on US treasury. It will mature Oct 22. But I want to re-invest part of it today, Oct 18.

When I log into my Treasury Direct account, there is option to edit my security, i.e. to reinvest and specify how much to re-invest. Instead, it has status, "Pending Maturity"

I sent an email, but I just wanted to know my options before the Treasury Dept opens tomorrow, i.e. Monday morning.

How to re-invest part of my investment instead of it all maturing on the 22nd.

Please help.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve by doing this? Understanding your motivation may help guide you to an alternative solution if what you are looking for is not exactly possible.

Comment: I am looking to re-invest part of the investment instead of it coming to my bank account.

Comment: I mean - why does it matter to you if you do it today instead of in 2 days? Does that make any specific difference to you?

Comment: I just wanted to know how far in advance from maturity date I can update reinvestment.

Comment: The simplest answer would be to just wait two days - if you needed to do it earlier than that for some reason, knowing the reason helps identify what would be a silly amount of effort, if it is even possible in the context of your goal anyway.